# My wallet balance says I have 12 mBTC but only allows me to send 2.63 mBTC. How can I fix this?

Tags: electrum, balance

I have 12mBTC but when I try to send a transaction, after I enter the amount (allocating enough for fees) Electrum says that I have only 2.63 mBTC. When I go back to check, every transaction I received is confirmed for more than a week, how do I fix this?

Comment: Try to check your address balance directly at the blockchain.

Comment: I'm using Electrum

Comment: Copy your public address from Electrum and enter in the search box at blockchain.info. There you will see exactly what is the balance. It may be a synchronizing problem of your wallet client.

Answer (score 1):

It might be, that you collected a lot of small transactions in your wallet. And if Electrum assembles a new transaction, it adds a fee, which is calculated in satoshis per byte, and for sure deducted from the amount you have. This way you can only spend less satoshis, than you actually have. In times of high fees, it does not make sense to create a tax. But today, as of July 2017, fees are very low, and you can give it another try. I posted a similar reply here:

[Why was the transaction fee more for a 20 mBTC transaction than for a 25 mBTC transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55137/why-was-the-transaction-fee-more-for-a-20-mbtc-transaction-than-for-a-25-mbtc-tr/55149?noredirect=1#comment64097_55149)